# How to get file access times in Haskell (cross-platform)?

Tags: file, haskell, cross-platform, lastaccesstime

I'd like to read file access times in a portable way. I found [`accessTime`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/libraries/unix-2.5.1.0/System-Posix-Files.html#v%3aaccessTime) in `System.Posix.Files`, but it's POSIX only. Is there a portable, cross-platform way that would work both on Windows and POSIX systems?

Answer (score 6):

How about [System.Directory.getModificationTime](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory/latest/doc/html/System-Directory.html#v%3agetModificationTime) for modification time?  For access time I'm not sure there is a portable way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need primarily access time.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows you can use System.Win32.getFileTime function, second time - is last access time. How i know - no crossplatform way for this task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [unix-compat](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix-compat/0.4.1.1/doc/html/System-PosixCompat-Files.html) to get both Windows and POSIX support for a lot of the functionality in the `unix` package.

Comment: I almost rejoiced that the problem is solved so easily, but unfortunately, looking at the implementation of the portable part, it doesn't really read access time, [it just copies modification time into it](https://github.com/jystic/unix-compat/blob/master/src/System/PosixCompat/Files.hsc#L314).

Comment: Wow, that's too bad. I'm glad to know of that caveat at least.

Answer (score 0):

As of directory-1.2.3 there is now [System.Directory.getAccessTime](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.6.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v%3AgetAccessTime).